# "Draw" tab is missing in Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word, pen

I have a UDB Pen Mouse device that I like to be able to draw with it on Word 2016. My PC is not a touch device but the USB pen mouse works nicely.

My word 2016 is part of Office 365 ProPlus installation.

The problem is that the "Draw" tab shown below is missing. My guess is that it only appears on touch devices?

[image]

How can I have the "Draw" tab in work 2016 on non-touch devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually access the draw tab in a non-touch device.
Go to options → customize ribbon →  make sure "Draw" is checked.

Look at my screenshot... I enabled the draw tab in PowerPoint:

[image: PowerPoint Options]

Answer (score 3):

The Ink Tools can be added to ribbon (permanently) trough Customize Ribbon in Options, it works for Power Point.

But Power Point was made by a separate company, unlike which, apparently the 'micro-scrab' are not adequate, so they've made Word to grey-out the tools, unless you have a hardware that fit their desires.

[image: Word 2016 \ ink tools]

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, you only get the Draw tab (formerly "Ink") if you have a touch-enabled or pen-enabled device.

> The Draw tab is currently only available for touch or pen-enabled devices in Word, Excel, and PowerPoint.  We chose that as the starting point since ink is a complicated feature, and we wanted to make sure we did it right, and obviously the best inking experience is when using a pen, so we wanted to start there.

[Quote Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_insider-office_install/i-havent-got-draw-tab-in-16065682016/12f07c5d-de40-4e0a-9048-a353db183c67)

And from the support.office.com site - [Draw and annotate with ink in Office 2016](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Draw-and-annotate-with-ink-in-Office-2016-c00b7319-2b50-4784-8114-47593d991c5c):

> Now, you can annotate with ink to make notes, highlight portions of your text, quickly create shapes, or write math equations and have them converted to text *on touch devices or pen-enabled devices*.

There currently is no way to activate it on non-touch and non-pen devices.

Comment: I do remember two weeks ago - out of nowhere- the "Darw" tab appeared on the same machine I have. I could draw with my mouse and it was great. I immediately bought my pen mouse, but I could not bring the "Draw" tab again. This is very strange.

Answer (score 0):

The chosen answer shows a Power Point screenshot. For Word, even though I checked the Draw tab in the ribbon to be displayed, it wouldn't. I coerced it to display by creating a new tab and adding one of the commands in the `Draw` tab within the new one. When done, both of them appeared.

See:
[image]